# Select from JSON Array postgresql JSON column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, select

I have the following JSON stored in a PostgreSQL JSON column

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "serverIp": "XXXX",
    "ruleId": 32321,
    "results": [
      {
        "versionId": 555555,
        "PriceID": "8abf35ec-3e0e-466b-a4e5-2af568e90eec",
        "price": 550,
        "Convert": 0.8922953080331764,
        "Cost": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to search for a specific priceID across the entire JSON column (name info) and select the entire results element by the PriceID.
How do i do that in postgresql JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses `exists` and `json(b)_array_elements()`. Assuming that your table is called `mytable` and that the jsonb column is `mycol`, this would look like:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.mycol -> 'data' -> 'results') x(elt)
    where x.elt ->> 'PriceID' = '8abf35ec-3e0e-466b-a4e5-2af568e90eec'
)
```

In the subquery, `jsonb_array_elements()` unnest the json array located at the given path. Then, the `where` clause ensures that at least one elment in the array has the given `PriceID`.

If your data is of `json` datatype rather than `jsonb`, you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead of `jsonb_array_elements()`.

---

If you want to display some information coming from the matching array element, then it is different. You can use a `lateral join` instead of `exists`. Keep in mind, though, that this will duplicate the rows if more than one array element matches:

```
select t.*, x.elt ->> 'price' price
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.mycol -> 'data' -> 'results') x(elt)
where x.elt ->> 'PriceID' = '8abf35ec-3e0e-466b-a4e5-2af568e90eec'
```

Comment: This is great! thank you so much
You don't know how many different queries i tried 
How can i just get a specific element within the results array like price and also i can i get the entire results array? 
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it worked great but when i try the same thing with an integer value i get an error message:ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer


select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.mycol -> 'data' -> 'results') x(elt)
    where x.elt ->> 'cost' = 800
)

Comment: @OferB: you need to cast to the proper datatye, so either `(x.elt ->> 'cost')::int = 800` or `x.elt ->> 'cost' = 800::text`

Comment: tried it like this:
select json_array_elements(t.info -> 'data' -> 'results') ->> 'Cost'
from table t
where exists (
    select 
    from json_array_elements(t.info -> 'data' -> 'results') x(elt)
    where (x.elt ->> 'ID')::int = 10
)
The result i got is where ID=10 and ID=1 
I just need the 10 , what did i do wrong?